# Fragment$InstantiationException Kotlin MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I'm pretty new to Kotlin and I'm trying to create some exercise application in Android Studio. Now, I am using the Fragment Architecture for my app. I have a problem while trying to play a particular song on a fragment when I press a button to activate it.

```
private var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.workout_music)
```

and then in my onCreateView function:

```
mediaPlayer?.start()
```

and getting this error:

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.bitamirshafiee.fitnessapp.ExerciseFragment: calling Fragment constructor caused an exception
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:465)
```

Comment: try moving private var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.workout_music) in to onCreate also

Answer (score 1):

`context` is `null`, because the constructor is called outside of the lifecycle, in field declaration, where `context` is not yet made. So that is why it can crash.

Making `mediaPlayer` a `lateinit` variable would remove the need for nullability. `private lateinit var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer`
then in `onCreateView` it could be initialised like `mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.workout_music)`.